# React Native: Get flexDirection row items to render on next render if outside of view's boundaries

Tags: android, ios, react-native, flexbox

I have a view container that is containing multiple `View` tags using `flexDirection: 'row'` property. However, issue arises when I have too many elements in the container `View`. For some reasons, the `View` components inside the container don't wrap and overflow outside the container. [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8kXp.png)

You can see that my view container has a border, but the contents are flowing outside of it.

My render function

```
render() {
    let test = ["Acute Pain","Acute Pain","Acute Pain","Acute","Acute","Acute","Acute"]

    let tagNames = test.map((tagName, index) => {
      return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#1bb393', padding: 3, borderRadius: 5, marginRight: 5}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'white', fontFamily: 'facit'}}>{tagName}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    })

    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, borderWidth: 1}}>{tagNames}</View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `flexWrap: 'wrap'`. Your `render` function must be like this:

```
return (
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1, borderWidth: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>{tagNames}</View>
)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. I found this after some digging through the docs. thanks!